# SQL UPDATE Function Date Columns using MS-SQLSERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, sql-update

I have a table which consists of 2 date columns. One column is a transaction date, and the next column is a date I've used as batch date where I group the dates based on what day of the date of transaction. 
My Table for demo purposes is was built on this sql script

```
CREATE TABLE [DateDemo1](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [mydate] [datetime] NULL,
    [batchdate] [datetime] NULL
)
```

The present data I have inserted is (date format is dd/mm/yyyy)

```
INSERT INTO [DateDemo]([mydate],[batchdate])  VALUES ('01/03/2017', '01/03/2017')
INSERT INTO [DateDemo]([mydate],[batchdate])  VALUES ('02/03/2017', '01/03/2017')
INSERT INTO [DateDemo]([mydate],[batchdate])  VALUES ('03/03/2017', '01/03/2017')
INSERT INTO [DateDemo]([mydate],[batchdate])  VALUES ('06/03/2017', '01/03/2017')
INSERT INTO [DateDemo]([mydate],[batchdate])  VALUES ('01/04/2017', '01/04/2017')
INSERT INTO [DateDemo]([mydate],[batchdate])  VALUES ('02/04/2017', '01/04/2017')
INSERT INTO [DateDemo]([mydate],[batchdate])  VALUES ('03/04/2017', '01/04/2017')
INSERT INTO [DateDemo]([mydate],[batchdate])  VALUES ('04/04/2017', '01/04/2017')
INSERT INTO [DateDemo]([mydate],[batchdate])  VALUES ('05/04/2017', '01/04/2017')
INSERT INTO [DateDemo]([mydate],[batchdate])  VALUES ('06/04/2017', '01/04/2017')
INSERT INTO [DateDemo]([mydate],[batchdate])  VALUES ('07/04/2017', '01/04/2017')
```

I intend to update the batchdate of each row into groups(1st of the month or 2nd of the month). using the 3rd day  of the month which determines the batchdate each row entry will be categorised in. An Example will be like the row of the 2nd of March 2017 should fall under the 2nd Feb 2017 batchdate. the 3rd of March 2017 will be on the 1st March 2017 batchdate, the 4th of March 2017 will be in the 2nd March 2017 batch date and for arguments sake the 7th of April will be in the 2nd of April 2017 batchdate. 
My desired result set I would like it to be as follows

```
id,    mydate,      batchdate
    1, 01/03/2017 ,  02/02/2017 
    2, 02/03/2017 ,  02/02/2017 
    3, 03/03/2017 ,  01/03/2017 
    4, 06/03/2017 ,  02/03/2017 
    5, 01/04/2017 ,  02/03/2017 
    6, 02/04/2017 ,  02/03/2017 
    7, 03/04/2017 ,  01/04/2017 
    8, 04/04/2017 ,  02/04/2017 
    9, 05/04/2017 ,  02/04/2017 
    10, 06/04/2017 ,  02/04/2017 
    11, 07/04/2017 ,  02/04/2017
```

I require an SQL UPDATE function that will give me the result I'm looking for. pseudo code will be welcome as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does 2nd of March 2017  get assigned 2nd Feb 2017? and based on March, wouldn't 7th of April  be 1st of April?

Comment: Well, you did a good job providing sample data, now all you have to do to make your question good is add your desired results and current attempts.

Comment: Expected output/results?

Comment: I shall have 2 batchdates for each month @SqlZim either 1st of the month for the 3rd date of the month or and the rest from 4th upwards will be 2nd day of the month.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I have made attempts with DateAdd and a casestatement I'm not winning, I wish to leave my approach open just to see what other approach is out there.

Comment: @KannanKandasamy let me manually write that.

Answer (score 1):

using two case expressions which modify the truncation of the date to month.

```
update DateDemo
  set batchdate = dateadd(day
                   , case when day(mydate) = (3) then 0 else 1 end
                   , dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, mydate ) 
                       + case when day(mydate) in(1,2) then -1 else 0 end
                   , 0)
                  );
select 
    mydate
  , batchdate
from DateDemo;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/CKGNS20776

returns:

```
+------------+------------+
|   mydate   | batchdate  |
+------------+------------+
| 2017-03-01 | 2017-02-02 |
| 2017-03-02 | 2017-02-02 |
| 2017-03-03 | 2017-03-01 |
| 2017-03-06 | 2017-03-02 |
| 2017-04-01 | 2017-03-02 |
| 2017-04-02 | 2017-03-02 |
| 2017-04-03 | 2017-04-01 |
| 2017-04-04 | 2017-04-02 |
| 2017-04-05 | 2017-04-02 |
| 2017-04-06 | 2017-04-02 |
| 2017-04-07 | 2017-04-02 |
+------------+------------+
```